# C# REST Request Method falling out of try block into catch block when correcting typo

Tags: c#

I've created this C# method to perform a JSON request getting the place_id from a text search. As far as I can tell the request itself works since I get a nullreferenceexception when trying to access non existent values where the message variable is set for example(Initially wrote "candidats" instead of "candidates"). However after correcting the typo it seems to only return from the catch block and I can't figure out why, what am I doing wrong here?

```
public async Task<string> GetPlaceAsync(string cityname, string countrycode)
    {
        string thereturn = "";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input="+ cityname + "," + countrycode + "&inputtype=textquery&key="+apikey);
        try
        { 
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jsonData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                var status = jsonData["status"].Value<string>();

                if (status != "ZERO_RESULTS")
                {
                    var message = jsonData["candidates"]["place_id"].Value<string>();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
                    return message;
                }
                else
                    thereturn = status;
            }
            else thereturn = "fail";
        }
        catch { thereturn = "Connection-error"; }
        return thereturn;
    }
```

edit: Since i sort of figured out what the problem is using David's answer of printing out the exception, we can move on to the next one which is not finding the place_id, here's the JSON data:

```
{
    "candidates": [
        {
            "place_id": "ChIJFWGA6nAUz0URs78HFrUdA7c"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: If the code is throwing an exception, catch and examine the exception.  It's *trying to tell you why* it's failing.

Comment: Thank you, then I know where I'm going wrong at least, the place_id part seems to not work even though it's in the result

Comment: Could you share the content of the jsonData, for instance the first candidate? My best guess would be it doesn't contain the property place_id.

Comment: Hey, as of now place_id is the sole field in candidates (I guess it might have to do with candidates being an array), I've added the full json respone